# On non-uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

In the book of **MATHEMATICAL
METHODS FOR
PHYSICISTS** by **Arfken et al.**, (Example 1.2.1 Non uniform convergence):

The series of functions $S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1-x\right)x^n$ is shown to not be uniformly convergent by providing the following explanation:
$$|1-(1-x^N)|<ε$$

"No matter what the values of N and a sufficiently small ε may be, there will be an x value
(close to 1) where this criterion is violated. The underlying problem is that x = 1 is the
convergence limit of the geometric series, and it is not possible to have a convergence rate
that is bounded independently of x in a range that includes x = 1."

Can anyone please explain why is it possible to have such an $x$ value which will always invalidate the inequality?

Comment: Try plotting a graph of $1-(1-x^N)$ for various values of $N$.  Do you ever see a graph where the function is always smaller than, say, $0.01$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

What happens if $x=1-1/N$?

Alternatively, take $\epsilon=\frac12$ and $x=\sqrt[N]{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Hi Monty.  Would you please let me know how I can improve my answer?  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If this was not useful, I am happy to delete it.  Looking forward to your reply.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.  ;-)